# How to define an array type with ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

I am currently developing my own language (DSL) with Antlr 4, and I wonder if it is possible to define an array type such as for example.

```
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];

STRING : '"' ( ~ '"' )* '"' ; // match string content
BOOLEAN: ('true' | 'fase');
INTEGER: DIGIT+ ;
DOUBLE: DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)*;
// x = ["string","string2",...]
ARRAY: ???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not define an array as a token (lexer rule), but rather as a parser rule. And you would not put strings, integers, etc. in the array, but rather expressions (which could match strings, integers, etc.):

```
array
 : '[' ( expression ( ',' expression )* )? ']'
 ;

expression
 : expression ( '*' | '/' ) expression
 | expression ( '+' | '-' ) expression
 | ... all other kind of expressions ...
 | STRING
 | BOOLEAN
 | INTEGER
 | DOUBLE
 | array
 ;
```

That way, `array` would match things like this:

```
["text", 42, false, 1 + 2 * 3, [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: thanks, actually i would like an array that contains values ​​of the same type so depending on your solution i should create 4 arrays (string array, integer array, boolean array, double array), is that true?

Comment: Sure, you could do that for a small language.

Comment: @Belgacem Can your arrays not contain variables, function calls or other expressions whose type isn't obvious from their syntax? If they can't, then yes, it's possible if you have a finite number of types and they can't be user-defined. That doesn't mean it's a good idea. For one it means, you'll have to introduce a new type of array literal for each new type you introduce. Also what about arrays of arrays? Another issue is that it leads to bad error messages. In general it's almost always more advisable to leave type checking to the type checker instead of trying to encode it in the grammar.